# Mockito Change argument value of non void method

Tags: java, mockito

I am trying to mock a method whose signature is :

```
public A doSomething(B b, String str){}
```

I tried to update str value by using doAnswer. However this method returns object A with values set conditionally. I am not able to find out a way to set specific str value to be passed to this method. Can anyone please let me know how this can be achieved? I cannot use powermock in my project.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that you want calls to your mocked method to modify their argument? That's impossible, since strings are immutable. Also, since no implementation of that interface can possibly do something like that, why would you want your mock object to do it?

Comment: what are you trying to test?  what do you meant by '' with values set conditionally'?'

Comment: @pvpkiran, I mean I cant just blindly return object A from doAnswer method. I want it to be returned through by the method.

Comment: @ohlec, there are few static methods from which I get this str value. And these methods are external to my project. I am not interested to mock those methods. I want to pass my own str value to doSomething method.

Comment: So, @Kolhapure do you want to return different results from `doSomething` depends on argument `str`?

Comment: @Kolhapure: I'm still confused. Surely, the values being passed to `doSomething` are determined by your code under test?

Comment: I am concentrating on the argument value.  I want to pass a string value in str argument of the method

Answer (score 4):

For one-off mocks, you can use [`InvocationOnMock.getArguments`](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.5.0/org/mockito/invocation/InvocationOnMock.html#getArguments()) to get the value of `str`:

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Foo>() {
  @Override public Foo answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
    A a = mock(A.class);
    when(a.someMethod()).thenReturn((String) (invocation.getArguments()[0]));
    return a;
  }
}).when(yourObject).doSomething(any(B.class), anyString());

// or with Java 8:
doAnswer(invocation => {
  A a = mock(A.class);
  when(a.someMethod()).thenReturn((String) (invocation.getArguments()[0]));
  return a;
}).when(yourObject).doSomething(any(), anyString());
```

...but as long as the method is mockable (visible and non-final), you can also write your new method inline as an anonymous inner subclass (or a static subclass defined elsewhere), which can accomplish the same thing without so much casting and Mockito syntax:

```
YourObject yourObject = new YourObject() {
  @Override public A someMethod(B b, String str) {
    A a = mock(A.class);
    when(a.someMethod()).thenReturn(str);
    return a;
  }
};
```

Comment: I am not interested in what is being returned. I was thinking to provide str as a stub. But looks like its not possible for non void method. I have refactored my code. Created a new method for the piece of code where I was reading this string and then returned value.

Comment: Be aware that you may not be using the term "mock" as it's commonly used ("replace the implementation of"), which normally applies to dependencies, not the system under test (SUT). If `doSomething` is a part of your SUT, then mocking or wrapping it is a bad idea, and you should call it directly in your tedt with any `str` you want. If it's in a dependency, then you can mock that dependency, ignore `str`, and return whatever you want. If the problem is in static method dependencies, there are many ways to intoduce a _testing seam_ without Powermock.

Comment: yeah I have got this problem because of static method. I cant use powermock as it is not an approved library in my clients repository.